# RegularExpressionValidator behaves differently than UnitTest RegEx

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I created a RegEx for our needs - wrote my UnitTest and after it passed I wanted to upgrade my FrontEnd to the new RegEx - but the RequiredFieldValidator SomeHow doesn't match the exact same string as the UnitTest does.

Here's the Unittest which passes fluently:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void BasicTest()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            var basicUnicodeRegEx = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:\p{IsBasicLatin}|\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}|\p{IsLatinExtended-A}|\p{IsLatinExtended-B}|\p{IsIPAExtensions}|[\u0302\u030C]|\p{IsLatinExtendedAdditional}){2,}[*]?)$");

            var isMatchString = "Floriân-D̂îétrich Wäßterh@gen 1823*";
            var IsNotMatchString = "べξぺき";
            Assert.IsTrue(basicUnicodeRegEx.IsMatch(isMatchString));
            Assert.IsFalse(basicUnicodeRegEx.IsMatch(IsNotMatchString));
        }
    }
```

And that's my ASP Controls which just don't like the exact same string nor even a basic A-Z one:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="edtNachname"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev_Nachname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="edtNachname" ErrorMessage="nope" ValidationExpression="^(?:(?:\p{IsBasicLatin}|\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}|\p{IsLatinExtended-A}|\p{IsLatinExtended-B}|\p{IsIPAExtensions}|[\u0302\u030C]|\p{IsLatinExtendedAdditional}){2,}[*]?)$">

                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

What's going on here? :o

Answer (score 0):

Seems like RegularExpressionValidator doesn't support NamedBlocks (ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks)

Changing to UniCode Ranges - in this case:

```
^(?:[\u0000-\u02AF]|[\u0302\u030C]|[\u1E00-\u1EFF]){2,}$
```

- works fine

Answer (score 0):

There are two important differences:

- The validator uses javascript to validate in the browser - so you are limited by the regex engine in javascript.
- The validator only matches when the *whole* string matches, it's as if the pattern is surrounded by `^` and `$`.

With your `\p{IsBasicLatin}`, I suspect the first point is your problem. You may set that validation to work server-side only to use the .Net regex engine, but this does need a postback.